# Infinite gas estimate for an empty function

Tags: solidity, gas, remix, gas-estimate

I have an empty function like below:

```
function myFunction(int[24] param1, int param2) public returns (int s) {
}
```

When I calculate the estimated gas value of this empty function, *Remix* is telling that it is **infinite**. Does anyone know why?

PS: I realized that if I remove `param1`, the estimated gas value is not **infinite** but 269.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Arrays, mapping, strings, structure and other types are deep types and Solidity does not really like this (by this I mean that it is complexe).

So yes, remix is not able to estimate the gas, but it would work with web3js for example (as the function is executed against the EVM).

Comment: I see. I was thinking that if the size of the array is **fix**, it should be able to estimate the gas value.